# Create points equally spaced along an area in QGIS

Tags: qgis

What's the best way to create points equally spaced in QGIS using a specific area?

For example, I want to create points spaced 1 meter in both X and Y direction.

The Image below describes better what I want:
[image: See this image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

'Vector  >  Research Tools  >  Regular Points'.
Allows for an input boundary layer and various ways to space your points.